# Add text to xml file through php in AS3

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3

im creating a very simple `CMS` panel for my website(i'm still lerning).
And I have some problems. I've created the panel in `Flash-AS3`, which loads the `php` file, which opens and saves the `xml data`. Here are the codes:

AS3 code:

```
function onClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var myXmlString:String = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><NEWSCONTENT><NEWS ID=\"" + idTxt.text + "\" IMG=\"" + sourceTxt.text +"\" TITLE=\"" + titleTxt.text + "\" DATE=\"" +   dateTxt.text + "\" CONTENT=\"" + contentTxt.text + "\"/></NEWSCONTENT>";

    trace(myXmlString);

    var myXml:XML = new XML(myXmlString);

    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("phpXML.php");
    req.data = myXml;
    req.contentType = "text/xml";
    req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    function onPHPLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        statusTxt.text = "Dane zostaly zaktualizowane!";
    }
loader.load(req);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPHPLoaded);
}

send_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClicked);
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])) {
    $xml = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
    $file = fopen("www.xml", "w");
fwrite($file, $xml);
    fclose($file);
    echo ($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]);
}

?>
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NEWSCONTENT>

    <NEWS ID="1" IMG="galerry/1b.jpg" TITLE="Let's begin!" DATE="23-11-2014" CONTENT="This is the content"/>

</NEWSCONTENT>
```

Everything works fine without `errors`, but it's not working the way I want to.

Now when I put `data/"strings"` to the `text fields` it removes all `xml data` and saves it again with the text i wrote. But i want to to add a next line `"<NEWS ID="1" IMG="galerry/1b.jpg" TITLE="Let's begin!" DATE="23-11-2014" CONTENT="This is the content"/>"` to the `xml` file.

I tried to change the: `$file = fopen("www.xml", "w");` to `$file = fopen("www.xml", "a");`, but this added whole `xml` code again to the first.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem, you have an xml file to save news and every time you want add a new one. If yes, you don't need to send every time all xml content, you can just send the new news attributes and append it to existing file. For that take this code :

**PHP Code :**

```
<?php

    if(count($_POST) == 5){

        $xml_path = 'news.xml';

        if(!file_exists($xml_path)){

            // if our xml file didn't exist, create it
            $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
            $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
            $root = $xml->createElement('NEWSCONTENT');
            $xml->appendChild($root);

        } else {

            // if our xml file exists, load it
            $xml = new DOMDocument();
            $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
            $xml->load($xml_path);

            // get our root element : NEWSCONTENT
            $root = $xml->documentElement;

        }   

        // create our news element
        $news = $xml->createElement('NEWS');

        // add atributes : ID, IMG, TITLE, DATE and CONTENT
        $attr_id = $xml->createAttribute('ID');
        $attr_id->value = $_POST['id'];

        $attr_img = $xml->createAttribute('IMG');
        $attr_img->value = $_POST['img'];

        $attr_title = $xml->createAttribute('TITLE');
        $attr_title->value = $_POST['title'];

        $attr_date = $xml->createAttribute('DATE');
        $attr_date->value = $_POST['date'];

        $attr_content = $xml->createAttribute('CONTENT');
        $attr_content->value = $_POST['content'];

        $news->appendChild($attr_id);
        $news->appendChild($attr_img);
        $news->appendChild($attr_title);
        $news->appendChild($attr_date);
        $news->appendChild($attr_content);

        $root->appendChild($news);

        $xml->formatOutput = true;

        // save our new xml file
        $xml->save($xml_path);

    }

?>
```

**ActionScript Code :**

```
var btn:Btn = new Btn();
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClicked);
    addChild(btn);

function onClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {

    var url:String = 'phpXML.php'; 
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        variables.id = idTxt.text;
        variables.img = sourceTxt.text;
        variables.title = titleTxt.text;
        variables.date = dateTxt.text;
        variables.content = contentTxt.text;

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        request.data = variables;
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPHPLoaded);
        loader.load(request);

    function onPHPLoaded(e:Event):void {

        statusTxt.text = "Dane zostaly zaktualizowane!"

    }   

}
```

Of course this minimalist working code do the job, it sends every time a news and save it in `news.xml` but you should add controls ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped and solved my problem. I'm very new in `php`, and i'm trying to create a `cms` with `php` with `add/edit/delete` from `xml database` function. I want to use it in `flash web`. Something like adding, editing, deleting and showing list of all news. I have found a great tutorial but it uses `mySQL database`, but I want to use `XML`. Here is a demo: http://falkencreative.com/forum/records/view.php 
Now i have trouble with edit and delete functions... 
Would it be a problem to show also solutions for the rest?

Comment: For me your demo looks fine, all operations work fine. You can use an `MySQL` db in your project and send data as xml to your flash this is better than just xml.

Comment: It's not my demo, it's from tutorial: http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/ I want to create ecsactly the same, but to use only `xml database`. I would use also `MySQL`, but i've never used it.

Comment: Ah OK ;) I recommend you to use MySQL + PHP + XML + Flash. Stock your data with MySQL, treat it with PHP which generate XMLs for Flash.